# Map onto function defined by derivative operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction

I'm trying to map different values onto the derivatives of a function. To test it, I've tried the following:

```
D[x^5, x] /@ {1}
```

And the output is:

```
{(5x^4)[1]}.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Clearly if the test works I'm hoping to get on output of 5.

Comment: try D[x^5, x] /. x -> {1, 2, 3}

Comment: If you try simply `Map[x, {1, 2, 3}]` you get  `{x[1], x[2], x[3]` which resembles your result. This means that Mma understands `x` as a head of some function, and according to the way how Map works, substitutes the list elements as its arguments. The workaround is to define a function of your choice, such as `f[x_] = D[x^5, x];`.  Then `f /@ {1, 2, 3}` yields the ´desired result. Play attention on `=` instead of `:=`.  If you define the function as `f[x_] := D[x^5, x];` Mma will take the numbers of the list and then substitute them into the formula creating absurd expressions like `D[1^5,1]`.